# How to convert HEX value to Datetime in .Net

Tags: c#, .net

I have a hex string like this "5290F419"It is corresponds to date time 2013-11-23 23:59:45.
How can i do this in .Net coding.I want to convert hex string to datetime with timezone Asia/Calcutta

Comment: What did not work with what you tried? Can you show us the code?

Comment: you can try parse this string to long and then convert to datetime

Comment: @Heather possibly TimeZone +5.30 :-)

Comment: Newfoundland Time! 30 minutes ahead of the rest of the world!

Comment: Your number is measuring whole seconds from Jan 1, 1970, 00:00:00 Zulu.

Comment: This is a duplicate of your question [How to convert HEX data to Datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373032/how-to-convert-hex-data-to-datetime) from two weeks ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"5290F419" is 1385231385 which is Sat, 23 Nov 2013 18:29:45 GMT, it's called time_t

here is basic convert from / to time_t in F#, code is pretty simple to get same in C#

```
let seconds dt = Convert.ToInt32( (dt - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local ) ).TotalSeconds ) 
let fromseconds (seconds : float, dtk : DateTimeKind) = (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 , ( dtk : DateTimeKind ) )).AddSeconds(seconds)
```

so I hope you can get int from hex

Comment: Actually i want to convert to datetime with timezone Asia/Calcutta

Comment: @vmb set DateTimeKind you need

Comment: @Heather..pls help..how in code??

Comment: @vmb `(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 , ( DateTimeKind.Local ) )).AddSeconds(Convert.ToInt32("5290F419", 16))`

Answer (score 2):

That's the hexadecimal representation of a date in unix epoch time - seconds since Jan 01 1970.

So convert it from hex to int.

```
int epoch = Convert.ToInt32("5290F419", 16); // second parameter is the numeric base
```

Then convert to a datetime object.

> TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(epoch); DateTime theDate =
>   Convert.ToDateTime(span);